# Work out timestamps / other data based on two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database:

```
tickets
ticket_updates
```

each table has a column called `ticketnumber` which match. there are sometimes multiple rows in `ticket_updates` where there is only one row in `tickets`

I want to be able to show the number of rows from `tickets` where `status = 'Completed'` but where it has been completed TODAY

for each row in the `ticket_updates` table there is a `datetime` column

As there are multiple rows in `ticket_updates` for each 1 row in `tickets` it will need to select the latest `datetime` from `ticket_updates` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple join and a little MySQL date function:

```
select
    count(sub.counter)
from
    (
        select distinct
            ti.ticketnumber as counter
        from
            tickets ti
            join ticket_updates tu
                on ti.ticketnumber=tu.ticketnumber
        where
            ti.status='Completed'
            and date(tu.datetime)=curdate()
    ) sub
```

If your datetime (Assuming that isn't the actual name) contains date AND time information, you will need to strip out the time component to compare it properly to the value returned by `curdate()` which is just a date of today.

The MySQL `date()` function returns just the date component of a date and time.

Edit: Corrected code to account for multiple relationship as correctly pointed out by @mituw16

Comment: This would potentially return an incorrect count based on a one to many relationship form tickets to ticket_updates.

Comment: @mituw16 You are totally correct and I have updated my answer to resolve that issue. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume there is a key linking these two tables. You might try something like this...

```
select count(*) as TicketCount from tickets 
join ticket_updates on ticket_updates.ticketnumber = tickets.ticketnumber 
where tickets.status='Completed' and ticket_updates.datetime = CURDATE()
group by ticket_updates.ticketnumber
```